# Error converting MVC4 view to PDF with Rotativa or RazorPDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razorpdf, rotativa

I am trying to convert a MVC4 view to Pdf. 
after a few minutes searching I found

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa/

and

https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorPDF

both give me the same problem that will be explained below:

I installed Rotativa 1.6.1 via nuget in a Mvc4 project.

my example action method looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewAsPdf TestPdf()
{
  return new ViewAsPdf("TestPdf");
}
```

my example view is structured in the following manner:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport"  />
    <title>TestPdf</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        This is a test!
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when I access the action method with my browser, I get the following result.

[image]

any Idea on why the pdf is not being shown?

this same error happens when I try with RazorPDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with asp.net mvc 4 and Rotativa. Adding a binding redirect for System.Web.Mvc in my web.config solve the problem for me.

```
<runtime>
    <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
           </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped a lot :)